# Client/Server SSL certificate ignored/forbidden with Require SSL set in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, ssl, https, iis-7

I have created a website that I want to be able to access using a smart card so I have enabled SSL on the site. When I am logged in remotely to the server and access the site on the https port using the smart card everything works fine. I receive my prompt and the site loads. However, if I try to access the same site, using the same card from a client pc then I receive the 403 Forbidden error.

```
Settings on the server(IIS 7.5) I have implemented or verified: 

1) Site is bound to specific port (not 443) with a type of https and a certificate that has a friendly name. 
2) SSL settings: Require SSL is checked, Require client certificates is selected (note: if I set it to accept, the site will load for the client but it never prompts for credentials) 
3) I have verified that when Require client certificates is set to accept, that the certificate it recognizes in the browser is the correct one (e.g. myserver.com) but as I said then I don't receive the prompt for credentials
4) Anonymous Authentication is enabled, all others disabled
5) applicationhost.config file set the following in location -> system.webserver -> security: 
     a) sslFlags = "Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert"
     b) under authentication set iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication to true
6) I have confirmed the necessary certificates exist in the Trusted Root and Personal folders for the Local Computer account. 


Settings for the client: 

1) I have confirmed the necessary certificates exist and match what the server has in the Trusted Root and Personal folders for the Local Computer account.
2) I have checked that the certificate chain in the browser does not show any errors going down the chain in both IE and Chrome
```

I created a self-signed certificate and added it to all the certificate stores on the server and the client and received the same behavior.

Using OpenSSL I have achieved the following results:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.com -CAfile c:\certs\godaddy.pem  -servername myserver.com

Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000160) 
depth=2 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go D
addy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http
://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G
2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.myserver.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.myserver.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.c
om/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.c
om/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certific
ate Authority - G2
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...29u1FZGXZnMUZCW5rlmZrkCAiBwDAB0/2t6BhyGh0JxydLWrRzJAZhW33KIem7IC...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.myserver.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy
.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2713 bytes and written 673 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: *** edited ***

    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: *** edited ***
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1439825381
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read:errno=10054
```

The OpenSSL results has one section that says 'No client certificate CA names sent' and before I added the -CAfile option I was getting the Verify 20 error unable to get local issuer certificate.

UPDATE to OpenSSL results:

Figured out how to use the debug feature and from what I can see here, it seems to negotiate SSL correctly and with the correct certificate as long as I pass in the CAfile path.

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:10168 -state -debug -CAfile c:\certs\godaddy.pem  -servername myserver

SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=2 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate 

Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.myserver.com
verify return:1

SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A

SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A

SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.myserver.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.c
om/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.c
om/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certific
ate Authority - G2
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.myserver.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy
.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2713 bytes and written 643 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: ***

    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: ***
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1439919398
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read from 0x2dd5b0 [0x2f06d3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
read:errno=10054
write to 0x2dd5b0 [0x2f4c23] (37 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
```

Additional openssl command:

openssl s_client -connect yourip:443 -prexit

...found on this [SO site here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014288/browser-is-not-prompting-for-a-client-certificate) did prove that in the list of acceptable certificates names was the Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority CA; however, I did not see *.myserver.com. Since *.myserver.com is chained to the Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority CA it seems that might be a normal process as indicated [by this site here](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/how-to-determine-certificate-authority/). On my local pc and the server the Go Daddy certificate exists in both the Trusted Root and Intermediate CA folders.

UPDATE - netsh:

I also tried the `netsh http add sslcert certhash= appid= clientcertnegotiation=enable` which executed sucessfully but did not result in any success.

UPDATE TO WIRESHARK INFO:

If I use Wireshark on my local pc to look at the traffic specifically to the server (display filter is set to search for ip.addr or ssl) I don't see any traffic at all generated by SSL. There's no Client or Server Hello or Certificate entry. I did verify in the first three SYN, SYN/ACK, and ACK packets that the IP addresses and ports were the correct values.

When I run Wireshark on the server I don't see any SSL traffic either specifically coming from my IP address. However, if I run Wireshark and my SSL website directly on the server, the site does resolve, works and prompts for credentials like it should but I discovered that the Certificate id-at-commonName equals a certificate different than I assigned to the site (*.myserver.com) which is *.vo.msecnd.net and belongs according to my research to the Baltimore CyberTrust Root certificate from Microsoft.

UPDATE - Repaired Certificate

Followed the instructions [on this site](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905) to repair the certificate and rule out it being faulty. I don't have an Entrust cert but the instructions at the bottom work the same.

Why am I not seeing a Client Hello? How can I troubleshoot lack of SSL handshake?

Some SO sites that I have used to try and resolve the issue include:

[OpenSSL errno 10054,connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485816/openssl-errno-10054-connection-refused-whilst-trying-to-connect-to-our-server)

[OpenSSL: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790572/openssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

[IIS 7.5 site with SSL fails, site without SSL works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359353/iis-7-5-site-with-ssl-fails-site-without-ssl-works)

RESOLUTION:

It appears the combination of certificate repair and setting the clientcertnegotiation did the trick but only after I rebooted the server.

Answer (score 1):

The correct steps are:

1. Set IIS SSL bindings up correctly
2. netsh http show sslcert and copy the values
3. Remove server SSL certificate binding with `netsh http delete sslcert`
4. Added server SSL certificate binding with `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=.... appid=.... sslctlstorename=ClientAuthIssuer clientcertnegotiation=enable`
5. Verified that settings were applied with `netsh http show sslcert`
6. (Windows 2012 R2 only) Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\SendTrustedIssuerList` to 1